# Creating a executable linux (e. g. LAMP) virtualization for windows?

Tags: linux, windows, webserver, executable, virtualization

We are developing a web application in TYPO3 Flow for one of our customers. Usally it should run on a web server over the internet, but there should also be an offline version for windows.

Our customer would sell this application with the two versions, on the web server it's combiled/crypted with Zend so his customer isn't able to change the code or anything like this.

Our idea for the offline windows application is, that we create an executable linux virtualisation with an installed apache and maybe with an pre-installed browser. So the user only starts the executable and the package will start with the browser pointing on the webapp.

Is there any solution, I think something like VMWare ThinApp (but I think this it's only for windows applications)?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can build a bootable USB stick based on a linux distribution, with a custom version of some distribution like webconverger, but the user must reboot to use it.

Or you can customize a Virtual Box image, based on Turnkey Lamp Stack per exemple, but the user must have a copy of Virtual Box (that's free).

How do you wont to deal with data persistence ?